# What Final Fantasy summons are referenced in the Gumball episode "The Console"?

Tags: game-identification, final-fantasy-series

The Amazing World of Gumball episode ["The Console"](https://theamazingworldofgumball.fandom.com/wiki/The_Console) has the titular character adventure in a JRPGstyle game world.

The final scene in the episode has Gumball, Darwin and Anais battle a Safer Sephiroth like monster and summon other characters to battle. You can watch the full scene [here](https://youtu.be/ZcBMM3JsOPA?si=nafp3ZBxgGLwaov4&t=199) on the official Youtube channel.

[image: Gumball | Inverted Paradox - The Enemy Within]

All of the characters seems to play out a specific Final Fantasy summon (most of the time a FF7 one), but I can't identify some:

- Sarah is clearly based on [Shiva's Diamond Dust](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CxP3frIKDfk)
- Hector ???
- Banana Joe is clearly [Cactuar's 1000 Needles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6WBfXHd_Ieo)
- Carrie ??
- Joanna seems like it would be [Ifrit's Hellfire](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0A6HbTOYjiI) (the fact that she throws only her denture instead of crashing on the foes could be part of the joke)?
- Nicolle seems to be based on [Knight of the Round](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sv9aI5RkoeQ) (the way she dashes in, attack and then goes away)
- Richard seems to fuse [Alexander](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KlBlmYxbvhI) (how he emerges from the ground) and [Bahamuth Zero](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zhmO9NOFHfo) (the orbital laser)

Can someone identify the missing two and / or suggest better matches for the existing ones?

Answer (score 4):

The game referenced is definitely FF7: the logo in the credits and the animation done by Gumball when doing the summoning are very similar, and also the background music kinda reminds it.

The very first animation, when a black hole opens in the ground and the enemy falls, reminds me of *Knight of the Round*'s **Ultimate End**.

Regarding your missing summons, they could be:

- Hector, based on [Titan](https://finalfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Titan_(summon)#Final_Fantasy_VII), just considering his big body.
- Carrie, based on [Typhon](https://finalfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Typhon), they both float and appear from nowhere.

Their attacks have nothing in common with those used in the video, so I might be wrong.

By the way, the boss seems a fusion between Sephiroth and Ultimecia's final form.

Comment: Titan came to mind for Hector as well, but came to same conclusion that their attacks are not similar at all

Comment: @Wondercricket I know, but I can't find best matches with FF7's summons

Comment: The episode contains multiple reference to Final Fantasy, like Gumball having Cloud's haircut at one point... but not just that. It is a worth watch for any JRPG lover. That said, the summons seems to be Final Fantasy specific. I originally though Carrie could be Diablos from FF8 but again, not a match. Anyway, I think it could safely be something from another Final Fantasy game, not just 7

Comment: "Titan" feels more like it's referencing Umaru the Yeti from FF6.

Comment: @trappski good match, but as I said I only considered FF7 summons as the game referenced is clearly that. Feel free to edit my answer.